# jQuery Tree plugin with specific options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, treeview

I am on the lookout for a jQuery plugin which sort of acts like jQuery Multisortable.
It should have the following options:

1. It has a left and right side. On the left there should be a tree structure menu and on the right it should show the content (like windows explorer).
2. On the left you should be able to create and delete a folder.
3. Items between the right and the left side should be drag-able and drop-able.

Can anyone point me a plugin which consists of all this please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Also, have you looked into [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)? It's a very popular tree api and the top google result for "jquery tree"

Answer (score 0):

I found this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neochief/KWeMM/ by just Googling for jquery multi sortable:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('ul.sortable').multisortable();
    $('ul#list1').sortable('option', 'connectWith', 'ul#list2');
    $('ul#list2').sortable('option', 'connectWith', 'ul#list1');
});
```

I think it meets your requirements, maybe with a bit tweaking from your side, but then please tell what you already tried/researched, and how it fails.

Comment: I am not much into jQuery. That's why I would like to have all the option in one plugin. It's nice if it's free, but it doesn't have to be.